# Subrahmanya Shodasa Nama Stotram from Skanda Purana

Tags: stotra, skanda-purana, kartikeya

Kindly let us know if anyone has the knowledge of the chapter number and verse numbers where the [Subrahmanya Shodasa Nama Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Subrahmanya_Shodasa_nama_stotram) occurs in Skanda Purana.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This stotra appears to be made by Sage Agastya, (Agastyo Bhagavan Rishi ).  There was a stotra on Skanda by Sage Agastya in Skanda Purana, but the content is different.  Do you want me to post it?   @ANGK

Comment: @srimannarayana k v - Please post it.  Also share the source (where you found it) if you know.  I also found a variation in the sanskritdocuments.org (https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_subrahmanya/subra16naamastotra.html?lang=iast)  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The Sanskrit version of eulogisation by Sage Agastya (agastya sthuthi) of Skanda has been posted below:

The online source of this part of Skanda Purana is available [here](https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/puranas/skanda_purana/skanda_purana_04kashi_01purva.pdf).

[image]

---

Translated version of eulogisation by Sage Agastya (agastya sthuthi) of Skanda has been posted below:

The English translation can be downloaded [from the site](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B0XpAgOLu_nHTTg3bzhHR3dlUGM&export=download).

[image]

[image]